# PySpark - Selecting all rows within each group

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe similar to below.

```
from datetime import date
rdd = sc.parallelize([
     [123,date(2007,1,31),1],
     [123,date(2007,2,28),1],
     [123,date(2007,3,31),1],
     [123,date(2007,4,30),1],
     [123,date(2007,5,31),1],
     [123,date(2007,6,30),1],
     [123,date(2007,7,31),1],
     [123,date(2007,8,31),1],
     [123,date(2007,8,31),2],
     [123,date(2007,9,30),1],
     [123,date(2007,9,30),2],
     [123,date(2007,10,31),1],
     [123,date(2007,10,31),2],
     [123,date(2007,11,30),1],
     [123,date(2007,11,30),2],
     [123,date(2007,12,31),1],
     [123,date(2007,12,31),2],
     [123,date(2007,12,31),3],
     [123,date(2008,1,31),1],
     [123,date(2008,1,31),2],
     [123,date(2008,1,31),3]
])

df = rdd.toDF(['id','sale_date','sale'])
df.show()
```

From the above dataframe, I would like to keep all rows upto the most recent sale relative to the date.  So essentially, I will only have unique date for each row. In the case of above example, output would look like:

```
rdd_out = sc.parallelize([
        [123,date(2007,1,31),1],
        [123,date(2007,2,28),1],
        [123,date(2007,3,31),1],
        [123,date(2007,4,30),1],
        [123,date(2007,5,31),1],
        [123,date(2007,6,30),1],
        [123,date(2007,7,31),1],
        [123,date(2007,8,31),2],
        [123,date(2007,9,30),2],
        [123,date(2007,10,31),2],
        [123,date(2007,11,30),2],
        [123,date(2007,12,31),2],
        [123,date(2008,1,31),3]
         ])

df_out = rdd_out.toDF(['id','sale_date','sale'])
df_out.show()
```

Can you please guide on how can I go to this result?

As an FYI - Using SAS, I would have achieved this results as follows:

```
proc sort data = df; 
   by id date sale;
run;

data want; 
 set df;
 by id date sale;
 if last.date;
run;
```

Comment: so you merely need a "representative record" or do you have specific logic to keep the last one?  In your example I'm concerened as " [123,date(2007,12,31),3]," doesn't show up in your output, and perphaps should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably many ways to achieve this, but one way is to use [Window](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html). With `Window` you can partition your data on one or more columns (in your case `sale_date`) and on top of that you can order the data within each partition by a specific column (in your case descending on `sale`, such that latest sale is first). So:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc
my_window = Window.partitionBy("sale_date").orderBy(desc("sale"))
```

What you can then do is to apply this `Window` on your DataFrame and apply one out of many Window-functions. One of the functions you can apply is [row_number](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.row_number.html) which for each partition, adds a row number to each row based on your `orderBy`. Like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number
df_out = df.withColumn("row_number",row_number().over(my_window))
```

Which will result in that the last sale for each date will have `row_number = 1`. If you then filter on `row_number=1` you will get the last sale for each group.

So, the full code:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, desc, col
my_window = Window.partitionBy("sale_date").orderBy(desc("sale"))
df_out = (
        df
        .withColumn("row_number",row_number().over(my_window))
        .filter(col("row_number") == 1)
        .drop("row_number")
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you would like replace "Department" with `sale_date` and "Salary" with `sale`.

Here's a none window example of the same thing... @Cleared's answer is excellent.  This answer would likely perform better on very large data sets than using a window.  Windows in my experience are slower than using logical equivalent with a groupBy. (Feel free to test what works better for you.)  Windows are very simple write and easy to understand, so likely a better choice if the data is small.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,Row
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkExample').getOrCreate()

data = [("James","Sales",3000),("Michael","Sales",4600),
      ("Robert","Sales",4100),("Maria","Finance",3000),
      ("Raman","Finance",3000),("Scott","Finance",3300),
      ("Jen","Finance",3900),("Jeff","Marketing",3000),
      ("Kumar","Marketing",2000)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,["Name","Department","Salary"])
unGroupedDf = df.select( \
  df["Department"], \
  f.struct(*[\ # Make a struct with all the record elements.
    df["Department"].alias("Dept"),\
    df["Salary"].alias("Salary"),\
    df["Name"].alias("Name")] )\
  .alias("record") )
unGroupedDf.groupBy("Department")\ #group
 .agg(f.collect_list("record")\  #Gather all the element in a group
  .alias("record"))\
  .select(\
    f.reverse(\ #Make the sort Descending
      f.array_sort(\ #Sort the array ascending
        f.col("record")\ #the struct
      )\
    )[0].alias("record"))\ #grab the "Max element in the array
    ).select( f.col("record.*") ).show() # use struct as Columns
  .show()
```

NOTE:
If you do not specify a partitionBy with a window it will ship all data to one node to be processed. This would be a performance issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would Window ship all the data to one node? Wouldn't a partition on the the partitionBy column be enough? Which I guess is the same partition as your answer, so I see no fundamental difference in terms of shuffling. I'm genuinely curious, I'm rather new to Spark my self and still trying to understand what's going on under the hood.

Comment: I'm actually a little bit wrong. If you don't specify a partition it DOES ship all data to one node. As you are specifying one it WILL distribute the information. But from my history with windows I've only seen 1 time when they were faster than avoiding them. I think this is caused by the extra bookkeeping to keep the window constructs in memory while it's being processed.